# How to create Codeigniter batch insert array

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I create a CI batch insert array which is like

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);
```

from my normal array which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [field_name] => email_title
            [field_value] => sample
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [field_name] => email_date
            [field_value] => 2013-07-02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [track_id] => 
            [camp_id] => 1
            [field_name] => email_template
            [field_value] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: What is the problem with existing array ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

For more information, read [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Can You please add about how to get this array using looping?

Comment: If you are here and didn't get that how to get this array then see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838618/5077564)

Answer (score 6):

This is your data
**At Controller**

```
$dataForDb[0]['track_id']=$data['track_id'];
$dataForDb[0]['camp_id']=$data['camp_id'];
$dataForDb[0]['field_name']=$data['field_name'];
$dataForDb[0]['field_value']=$data['field_value'];

$dataForDb[1]['track_id']=$data['track_id'];
$dataForDb[1]['camp_id']=$data['camp_id'];
$dataForDb[1]['field_name']=$data['field_name'];
$dataForDb[1]['field_value']=$data['field_value'];

$dataForDb[2]['track_id']=$data['track_id'];
$dataForDb[2]['camp_id']=$data['camp_id'];
$dataForDb[2]['field_name']=$data['field_name'];
$dataForDb[2]['field_value']=$data['field_value'];

$fid=$this->model_modelName->functionName($dataForDb);
```

And insert data as batch insert
**At Model**

```
$this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array is ok. Just put your array into a variable like

```
$data=array();//put your array
```

and then

```
 $this->db->insert_batch('yourTable', $data);
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

your normal array structure matchs with the array stucture of batch insert..

so just use batch insert query to insert the data.

```
 $this->db->insert_batch('yourTable', $data);
```

$data is your normal array.