# How to get all data from array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert data in mysql as well as show in browser the insert value Is it possible to get all $insertdata value

```
class CommonController extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('common_model'); //load your model my model is "common model"
  }

 public function add_work(){
 $names = $_POST['name'];
 $works = $_POST['work'];

 foreach($names as $key => $name){
             $name= "your specified name";
             $insertdata = array();
             $insertdata['work'] = $works[$key];
             $insertdata['name'] = $name;
             $this->common_model->insert($insertdata);
        //$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work(name,work) values ( '$name','$work')");
            }
  //view code will add here to show data in browser
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely yes, look at this code:

```
$allValues = array(); // array to contains inserted rows 
foreach($names as $key => $name){
             $name= "your specified name";
             $insertdata = array();
             $insertdata['work'] = $works[$key];
             $insertdata['name'] = $name;
             $this->common_model->insert($insertdata);

             array_push($allValues,$insertdata);
        //$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work(name,work) values ( '$name','$work')");
            }
  foreach($allValues as $insertRow){
     echo $insertRow['work'];
     echo $insertRow['name'];
  }
  //view code will add here to show data in browser
}
```

or you can display the inserted row in your code after this line:

```
$this->common_model->insert($insertdata);
echo $insertdata['work'];
echo $insertdata['name'];
```

Comment: getting `Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`
and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: you should add this line before the loop:
$allValues = array(); // define array

Comment: Now `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: sorry my bad, you can't echo an array.. but you can make a new loop for $insertRow['work'] and echo every value.

Comment: `echo $insertdata['work'];`
and
`echo $insertdata['name'];`
just shows one data. I need to show all data

Comment: If I put `  foreach($stockdata as $insertRow){
     echo $insertRow['name'];
  }`
it shows `Message: Illegal string offset 'name'`

Comment: try to use my code above.. what I did is defining a new array and push every row($insertdata) you insert into database to it.
after the loop finish, $allValues have all rows inserted to database, and you can display them.

Comment: Use `insert_batch()` db method instead `insert()` to avoid insert in foreach loop. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array).