# how to insert multi-dimensional array to the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is my code:

```
Array
(
    [head_family] => 1234
    [house_name] => abc
    [house_no] => 12
    [relationship] => son
    [family_ms_id] => KERTVMPMJF318
    [member_ms_id] => KERTVMPMJM318
)
Array
(
    [head_family] => varun
    [house_name] => nila
    [house_no] => 12
    [relationship] => son
    [family_ms_id] => KERTVMPMJF318
    [member_ms_id] => KERTVMPMJM318
)
```

**Controller:**

```
$this->Enrollment_model->add_member($appended);
```

**Model:**

```
function add_member($appended) {
        $this->db->insert('members', $appended);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array

Comment: `$this->db->insert_batch`

Comment: please let us know what is you want to do...

Comment: pls always be responsive to the given answers, mark with check as green and do upvote if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach would be inserting as `JSON` string.
So first create a database column with type as `LONGTEXT`

Then use this in Model:

```
function add_member($appended) {
     $json_array = json_encode($appended);
        $this->db->insert('members', $json_array);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

And when fetching from database :

```
$appended = json_decode($json_array);
```