# security on insert batch? codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xss

can anyone know how to preventing user input, on codeigniter if i use insert_batch? sorry bad english
code like this

```
$data[] = array(
                    'id_invoice'    =>  $this->input->post('id_invoice'),
                    'id_product'    =>  $key['id_product'],
                    'id_fabrics'    =>  $key['id_fabric'],
                    'id_option'     =>  $id_option,
                    'name'          =>  $key['name'],
                    'number'        =>  $key['number'],
                    'id_size'       =>  $key['size'],
                    'comment'       =>  $key['comment']);
```

and use insert batch like this

```
$this->orders->insert_order_mix($data);
```

Comment: use second param `true` in `$this->input->post('id_invoice', true),` to prevent injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So Simple You can remove abuse tags and data from user input

```
//Change This

$this->orders->insert_order_mix($data);

// to 

$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data); // You have to clean Data with XSS Filtering
$this->orders->insert_order_mix($data);
```

This method Clean your all abuse data with [removed] keyword

if user can input any script then XSS filtering remove as per below

```
$name = '<script>Your Name</script>';
echo $name; // Output : <script>Your Name</script>

// But you use XSS then output is change as per below

$name = '<script>Your Name</script>';
$name = $this->security->xss_clean($name);
echo $name; // Output : [removed]Your Name[removed]
```

> Or You can use very simple with edit your config file

```
// Change global_xss_filtering value FALSE to TRUE;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: I am trying your suggestion but have a same output

Comment: my final action maybee use htmlspecialchars, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the concept of Batch Insert. Please [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array) to get a good understanding of Batch Insert. Now for your issue, it's very good to be concerned about security these days as said

> Always filter input and escape output, Never trust data.

You can Use [Codeigniter Security Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) to secure your data.

E.g

```
$data=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post());
```

OR

```
$postData=$this->input->post();
$data=$this->security->xss_clean($postData);
```

Furthermore you can avoid Cross Site Request Forgery by using [CSRF token](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) in your Forms

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, i am not sure about your answer because i am using ajax to get data, and data is on array format, and this is my code to process on controller

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed');
    } else {
        $input = $this->input->post('ar_dat');
        $option = $this->input->post('list_option');
        if ($option == null){
            $id_option = '';
        } else {
            $id_option = implode(',',$option);
        }
        foreach ($input as $key) {
            $data[] = array(
                'id_invoice'    =>  $this->input->post('id_invoice'),
                'id_product'    =>  $this->input->post('id_product'),
                'id_fabrics'    =>  $this->input->post('id_fabric'),
                'id_option'     =>  $id_option,
                'name'          =>  $key['name'],
                'number'        =>  $key['number'],
                'id_size'       =>  $key['size'],
                'comment'       =>  $key['comment']);
        }
        $this->orders->insert_order_uniform($data);
    }
```