# Unable to insert array into database

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am inserting multiple data from multiple forms into database but encounter an error at column **photo**

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

**Controller**

```
if(!empty($_FILES['user_profile_file']['name'])){
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['user_profile_file']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

        $studentImg = '';

        $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['user_profile_file']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['user_profile_file']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['user_profile_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['user_profile_file']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['user_profile_file']['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH."uploadfiles/users/student-img";
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 0;

        $studentImgNew = uniqueId();
        $config['file_name'] = $studentImgNew;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();

            $studentImg[$i]['photo'] = $fileData['file_name'];

            $studentData[] = array(
                'name'            => $_POST['user_name'][$i],
                'nric'            => $_POST['user_nric'][$i],
                'gender'          => $_POST['user_gender'][$i],
                'photo'           => $studentImg,
                'email'           => $_POST['user_email'][$i],
                'password'        => md5($_POST['user_password'][$i]),
                'is_active'       => '0',
            );
        }
    }
}

$this->User_account_model->create($studentData)
```

**Model**

```
function create($studentData){
    foreach ($studentData as $key => $studentDatas) {
        $insertStudentData[$key] = array(
            'parent_id'      => $parent_id,
            'email'          => $studentDatas['email'],
            'password'       => $studentDatas['password'],
            'name'           => $studentDatas['name'],
            'nric'           => $studentDatas['nric'],
            'gender'         => $studentDatas['gender'],
            'photo'          => $studentDatas['photo'],
            'is_active'      => $studentDatas['is_active'],
        );

        $this->db->insert('users_student', $insertStudentData[$key]);
    }

    if($this->db->affected_rows() != 1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I do `print_r()` I can get the exact data to be inserted into the database.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 11
            [email] => testing.mael@gmail.com
            [password] => e02cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
            [name] => testing
            [nric] => 123123
            [gender] => 0
            [photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [photo] => 5955cac09b8f71.jpg
                        )

                )

            [is_active] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 11
            [email] => testing.mael@gmail.com
            [password] => e13cc542ac59075b9643s5152d234g59
            [name] => testing sister
            [nric] => 123123
            [gender] => 0
            [photo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [photo] => 5955cac09b8f72.jpg
                        )

                )

            [is_active] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: May be you have problem with that ```[photo]``` array key... you have to insert single format in any field, not group format...

Comment: `'photo'          => $studentDatas['photo'][0],` Try this

Comment: You get the error because you are trying to add an array in `photo` column.

Comment: @ankitsuthar : perfect catch

Comment: @ankitsuthar If I put `'photo' => $studentDatas['photo'][0],` this it will return my photo value null

Comment: Please tell me what is the data type of your column `photo`

Comment: try json encoding like json_encode($studentDatas['photo']) to save photo field.

Comment: @VibhaBharwad I tried applying `json_encode` only for photo but getting error `Illegal string offset 'photo'`

Comment: @EatenTaik i have added the answer. Please try that.

Comment: @ankitsuthar I have solved my issue :)

Comment: Can you please vote up if my answer helps you to get it.

Comment: Sure for the insert_batch. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue. From my controller I changed the assigning array like this :

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')){
    $fileData = $this->upload->data();

    $studentImg[$i]['photo'] = $fileData['file_name'];

    $studentData[] = array(
        'name'            => $_POST['user_name'][$i],
        'nric'            => $_POST['user_nric'][$i],
        'gender'          => $_POST['user_gender'][$i],
        'photo'           => $studentImg[$i]['photo'],   // Edited row
        'email'           => $_POST['user_email'][$i],
        'password'        => md5($_POST['user_password'][$i]),
        'is_active'       => '0',
    );
}
```

And my foreach model I changed to this :

```
foreach ($studentData as $studentDatas) {
    $insertStudentData[] = array(
        'parent_id'      => $parent_id,
        'email'          => $studentDatas['email'],
        'password'       => $studentDatas['password'],
        'name'           => $studentDatas['name'],
        'nric'           => $studentDatas['nric'],
        'gender'         => $studentDatas['gender'],
        'photo'          => $studentDatas['photo'],
        'is_active'      => $studentDatas['is_active'],
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('users_student', $insertStudentData);
```

And the output of those array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 11
            [email] => testing.mael@gmail.com
            [password] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
            [name] => testing
            [nric] => 123123
            [gender] => 0
            [photo] => 5955cac09b8f71.jpg
            [is_active] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 11
            [email] => testing.mael@gmail.com
            [password] => e13cc542ac59075b9643s5152d234g59
            [name] => testing sister
            [nric] => 123123
            [gender] => 0
            [photo] => 5955cac09b8f72.jpg
            [is_active] => 0
        )

)
```

By the way, thank you for everyone that trying to help! I appreciate it.

Comment: I am just suggesting here, You can use `insert_batch` rather than using insert query in `foreach` loop because it using the query in the loop isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert an array inside the for `insertStudentData[key]`.

Try This:

```
 $insertStudentData[$key] = array(
        'parent_id'      => $parent_id,
        'email'          => $studentDatas['email'],
        'password'       => $studentDatas['password'],
        'name'           => $studentDatas['name'],
        'nric'           => $studentDatas['nric'],
        'gender'         => $studentDatas['gender'],
        'photo'          => $studentDatas['photo'],
        'is_active'      => $studentDatas['is_active']['0']['photo'],
    );

$this->db->insert('users_student', $insertStudentData[$key]);
```

if you are trying to insert multiple rows, then you can use [insert_batch](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#inserting-data)

I have tried your code on my side and it gets perfectly correct. it added the multiple rows to the table. This is what I have done.

```
function create($studentData){
$insertStudentData = ''; //Create a Variable
    foreach ($studentData => $studentDatas) {

        $insertStudentData[] = array(
            'parent_id'      => $parent_id,
            'email'          => $studentDatas['email'],
            'password'       => $studentDatas['password'],
            'name'           => $studentDatas['name'],
            'nric'           => $studentDatas['nric'],
            'gender'         => $studentDatas['gender'],
            'photo'          => $studentDatas['photo']['0']['photo'],
            'is_active'      => $studentDatas['is_active']
        );

    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('users_student', $insertStudentData[$key]);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() != 1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `insert_batch`. Let me try it first

Comment: I receive error `Illegal string offset 'photo'` when I use the `insert_batch` and this error as well `array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given`

Comment: The warning indicates that the array value is empty. Check for a value associated with the key before trying to assign it to some other variable.

Comment: Please First Check that the value is exist or not using `isset`

Comment: I do `print_r($insertStudentData)` outside the `foreach` and I manage to get all the result. There is no empty field.

Comment: I removed `[0]['photo']` from my foreach and I am not getting `Illegal string offset 'photo'` anymore but it return me a lot of error and one of them is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`