# How to post multiple inputs in database

Tags: forms, loops, codeigniter, input

I'm working with Codeigniter, on a sales targets' form for salesmen.
They have to input values for each product, locality, year, etc.
Product and locality are already get with existing database: no need to set rules (see controller).

When I checked the post (with enable_profiler of Codeigniter), I get this:
[image: enable_profiler result]

The problem is these datas don't insert into the database table.
I read and tested a lot, but always blocked.

Here is my model:

```
    public function add($params)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->table, $params);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

My controller:

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'required|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('prevision', 'Prevision', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('value', 'Value', 'required|integer');
            
            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $params = array(
                    'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
                    'prevision' => $this->input->post('prevision'),
                    'locality_id' => $this->input->post('locality'),
                    'product' => $this->input->post('product'),
                    'value' => $this->input->post('value'),
                );
    
                $this->Objectif_model->add($params);
                redirect('admin/objectif');
            } else {
                $this->layout('admin/objectif/add');
            }
```

And my view with inputs:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
<tr class="form-group">
    <td class="bg-warning">
    <?= $product->grp_product; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="bg-warning product">
    <?= $product->code; ?>
    </td>
        <?php foreach ($localities as $locality ) : ?>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control valeur" placeholder="Value k€" name="value[]" data-validation="number" data-validation-ignore="./" data-validation-optional="true" />
            <input type="text" name="year[]" />
            <input type="text" name="prevision[]" />
            <input type="text" name="product[]" value="<?= $product->code ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="localite_id[]" value="<?= $locality->id ?>" />
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope you will help me.

Comment: *but always blocked.*: can you please show us the error message, also check what `$this->table`echo's out, thanks

Comment: no error message. Nothing happens (no data into the table)

Comment: did you try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); die();` to debug your model function `add()`

Comment: I got "Message:  Undefined variable: params"

Comment: I suugest you follow this tutorial: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation

Comment: I follow the doc and also this post 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838561/unable-to-insert-array-into-database/44838618#44838618). In my model, I replaced insert_id by insert_batch and I added a foreach loop. In my controller, I made a for loop. And now I have "Message: Undefined index: id" and my array is empty. I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer.
In my controller, I had to pass each post in a variable and made a loop.

```
    //action post in a var for each data
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $prev = $this->input->post('prevision');
    $year= $this->input->post('year');
    $locality_id = $this->input->post('locality_id');
    $product = $this->input->post('product');
    $value= $this->input->post('value');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $count_id = count($id);

        if (isset($id)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count_id; $i++) {
                $obj[$i] = array(
                    'id' => $id[$i],
                    'prevision' => $prev,
                    'year' => $year,
                    'locality_id' => $locality_id[$i],
                    'product' => $product[$i],
                    'value' => $value[$i]*1000
                );
            } // endfor

            if (isset($obj)) {
                $this->Objectif_model->add_obj($obj);
            } // endif
         }// endif isset
    }// endif form validation
```