# Codeigniter database backup - Insert multiple rows without repeating “INSERT INTO”

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, database-backups

I'm trying out to find a way to backup my database using Codeigniter "Database Utility" but without repeating “INSERT INTO”, I mean everything works perfectly, but when we see the generated sql file we see something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Membership (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', '5/5/1960')

INSERT INTO Membership (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (2, 'Hello", 'World", '4/9/1975')

INSERT INTO Account(ID, Type, Effective_Date, Status)
VALUES (1, 'Gold', GetDate(), 'Active')

INSERT INTO Account(ID, Type, Effective_Date, Status)
VALUES (2, 'Platinum', GetDate(), 'Inactive')

INSERT INTO Participant(ID, Code, Type)
VALUES (1, 002, 'A')

INSERT INTO Participant(ID, Code, Type)
VALUES (2, 002, 'A')
```

The which is so slow whenever we import in another database. I want to get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #temp_table (1, 'John', 'Smith, '5/5/1960', 'Gold', 'Active', '002', 'A')
.
.
.
.
so on
```

using only one INSERT INTO, is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CodeIgniter `insert_batch()` function

Follow this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array) to see how it works:

Answer (score 0):

Create a multi-dimensional array with field and values like this, and use codeigniter inset_batch() function to insert all these in a single query.

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'ID' => 1,
            'FirstName' => 'John',
            'LastName' => 'Doe',
            'DOB'      => '5/5/1960'
    ),
    array(
            'ID' => 2,
            'FirstName' => 'John',
            'LastName' => 'Smith',
            'DOB'      => '5/5/1960'
    )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('temp_table', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, Database Utility is quite slow also, due to string concatenation, if [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) is enabled on your server, then `mysqldump`  can be used, here is working code, which will export current database.

```
public function backup_current_db()
{
    $db_user=$this->db->username;
    $password=$this->db->password;
    $db=$this->db->database;

    $filename =  $db . "-" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql";
    $mime = "application/octet-stream";

    header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

    $cmd = "mysqldump -u '$db_user' --password='$password' --no-create-info --complete-insert '$db' ";
    passthru( $cmd );

    die();
}
```