# Php - Insert Multiple Rows in Ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array ['abc','xyz'];

I want to insert two rows but in one go

I dont want

```
loop(){
 $this->db->insert()
 }
```

this will run insery query two times

Using CI Framework
and this array comes from user

Comment: What DB controller are you using?

Comment: @WKoppel Using CI Framework

Comment: inside loop write insert query

Comment: @Daan This is something manual taking values from input in array what can i do?

Comment: Last time I used CI I'm quite sure you could insert arrays of information to the DB

Comment: Please read the manual before asking, I found this on google within 10 seconds: `insert_batch` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Comment: @Daan I know about this insert_batch() but how to convert my array into the format this method wants not manually keeping in mind that this array comes from user so its length can be upto 100 index also

Comment: @NeerajWalia Check my answer, haven't tested it. But should work fine.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array

Comment: @ManojSingh In your link there is no way defined like how to create that array dynamically it is created static , so its no way duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($this->input->post("name") as $value) {        
            $name[] = array(
                'name'=>$value,
            );
        }
$this->db->insert_batch("names",$name);
```

Comment: would you like to explain the code so that the OP decides why he needs to update the code to this one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please provide some description to your code-example.

Answer (score 0):

**yourModel.php**

```
public function urfunctionName($data)
{
  foreach($data as $res)
  {
     $this->db->insert('table_name',$res);
  }
}
```

> Hope it will work you

Comment: I told you not to do this in loop

Comment: Show me your expected result

Comment: I will get same results but your code will run query equal to length of my array like if array has 100 indexes it will run 100 times which is not good i want to insert 100 rows in one run thanks for help insert_batch() did it thankyou all

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build your 'batch' insert query first. After that call the `insert_batch` method.

```
$array = ['abc','xyz'];
$batchInsertArray = buildBatchInsertArray($array);

$this->db->insert_batch('myTable', $batchInsertArray);

function buildBatchInsertArray(array $array): array
{
    $batchInsertArray = [];

     foreach ($array as $item) {
       $batchInsertArray[] = [
           'columnName' => $item
       ];
    }

    return $batchInsertArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'),  ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

Referance :: [query_builder inserting-data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)